# Flexcube's eodm automatization

Tags: java, sql, oracle

We have more than 200 branches in our bank. We do not provide access to our branch's admins, and every day our admin from the headquater must to start the procedure of eodm in each branch manualy. Is there any way we can launch this process automatical?

Comment: Schedule job to run every day at specific our, trigger... It all depends.

Comment: Can it be done within frontend (screen)? Or i need to use only backend?

Comment: Privet. You can probably schedule a job to run using your front end, I'm not sure, I do not know all details and what front end you have. But usually job scheduling is done with 3rd party software or it can easily be done with Oracle dbms_schedule, which is back end. I have never used the front end for jobs, don't know, sorry. Have a good weekend.

Comment: All is clear, thank you!